# Adding a MapPageRoute to my webforms application is causing missing dll problems

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

My .NET 4 Webforms application works fine EXCEPT when I add the below to my Global.asax.cs file.

For some reason once I push this to my server, I keep getting errors saying it can't find the System.Web.Mvc dll, then System.Web.Razor, then System.Web.Webpages.  I kept manually added them and setting copyLocal=true.

Now it is saying it can't find System.Web.WebPages.Deployment 2.0.  I am getting tired of adding the dll's each time as I am afraid this will keep on going.

Is this normal or is there something else wrong?

```
 void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.MapPageRoute(
                "login-redirect",
                "login", 
                "~/users/login.aspx");
        }

        void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
```

Again if I remove the above everything is fine but I really need to get this route working as I want to redirect all requests that have /login to the /users/login.aspx page.

Comment: You should actually set copyLocal = false because once you rebuild the solution, you would know why the dlls are not being copied.

Answer (score -1):

use NuGet and get the ASP.NET MVC package

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/5.2.3